# How to search a symbol in current file which is not in workspace?

Tags: visual-studio-2022

While I am in a source file of some library, I want to search a symbol in this file.

I know visual studio has "go to" commands which is default triggerd by "ctrl + t". The problem is it only searches within the workspace.  I haven't found a good way to do this.
If you are familiar with jetbrains ides, there is a "file member" command which is default "ctrl + f12". And it is exacly what I want.

edit:

[image: search symbol in current file]

Like the picture above, I can search a symbol in current file by check that "Current Document" icon. This is good. However, if I open a source file of some library, this does not work.

[image: search symbol failed]

There is apparently a `SimpleMove` function in this file, but it can't find it.

Comment: Is this the Jet Brains command you speak of? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Navigation_and_Search__Go_to_File_Member.html I'm trying to understand what you are talking about more to try and provide a Visual Studio answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have modified my description. I hope you can understand now.